# An ANCOVA pre-post framework for multilevel data?

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, ancova, pre-post-comparison

I have a continuous outcome/dependent variable that is measured multiple times before and after an treatment/intervention per subject. The multiple measures are performed very closely together and are done about 10 times, because single measures are known to be variable. So you have 10 measures before, and 10 after intervention for each subject.

To test the effect of the intervention I would prefer to perform an ANCOVA type of analysis, where the outcome after intervention is controlled by the baseline outcome. I'm not very good at official mathematical annotation, but my best attempt would be:

M(post intervention) ~ M(pre intervention) + Treatment | *Where M is the measure assessed before and after treatment.*

However, is this possible (without using summary data) using a multi-level approach through linear mixed models? I've now resorted to an intermediate solution where I keep the M(post intervention) multi-level, but do summarize the M(pre-intervention) using a mean per subject.

Comment: Sure, you have 10 paired observations per subject. Adding a random intercept per subject takes care of the clustered nature of the data. So something along the lines of `lmer(post~pre + group + (1|ID))`.

Comment: Why would you "prefer an ANCOVA type of analysis" over multilevel? ANCOVA makes some assumptions that are typically not reasonable (especially sphericity).  It also doesn't deal well with missing data (if you have any).

Comment: @PeterFlom Sorry for being unclear. I used "ANCOVA" here more to describe the structure of the fixed part of the model, thus correcting for baseline performance (or adding baseline performance as a coavariate) that similar to an ANCOVA. I do prefer a multi-level model, though am wondering if the correction for baseline measure/performance can also be done in a multi-level manner.

Comment: @COOLSerdash My concern here is that the clustered observations are not directly paired in a sense that out of the 10 measurements the first pre measure is not specifically paired with the first out of 10 post measures. If you would the model you propose, would have a df with the first measurement of the pre and post per subject being on the same row, and the second, and so forth. Does such a model not pair pre and post measurements by the sequence of the measurement? I understand that the mixed model can be used to define clusters, though does it also take care of the row-based relation?